# Export crontab to a file

Tags: cron

How can I export the contents of the crontab to a file?

I need it because I'm switching usernames and do not want to lose the data in the crontab.

Answer (score 188, accepted):

Create the backup (export):

```
crontab -l > /some/shared/location/crontab.bak
```

Import it from the new user:

```
crontab /some/shared/location/crontab.bak
```

Answer (score 2):

To add some more cool commands for backuping and restoring crontab. Might be useful.

Backup periodically current cron with cron :)

```
0 9 * * * crontab -l | gzip > /backups/'crontab-'$(date +"\%Y\%m\%d-\%H\%M\%S")'.gz'
```

Restore Single User Cronjobs from Backup. Below is two commands which will restored jobs from backup created in above step.

```
crontab cron-backup.txt
crontab -u john john-cron-backup.txt
```

Backup all users crontabs

```
zip -r cronjobs-all.zip /var/spool/cron
```